# How to calculate MDA for face recognition in matlab

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, pca, face-recognition, reduction

I want to do PCA and then MDA (Multiple Discriminative Analysis) in order to reduce the dimensions of the dataset from 99^2 to 49 (face recognition).

My first step was reducing dimensions from 99^2 to 50 by PCA. Now I want to use MDA to reduce from c to c-1 -> from 50 to 49. 
I've tried this code but I get complex values in the 'Answer', which is wrong.

```
%   calculate PCA
mat_mean = mean(trainData(:));
normalized_train = trainData - mat_mean;
A = normalized_train/std(normalized_train(:));
S1 = A * A';
[V,Z] = eigs(S2,50);
Wpca = A'*V*Z;


%    calculate MDA
[Sb,Sw] = scattermat(Wpca);
Sb1=Wpca*Sb*Wpca';
Sw1=Wpca*Sw*Wpca';
[Answer,ready1] = eigs(Sb1,Sw1,49);
```

Any suggestions what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have a very small  imaginary part in your Answer ? If so it can be a bad approximation only

Comment: MDA it's like LDA but for multiclass.@A.Donda

Comment: Dont have imaginary part at all... @GerardRozsavolgyi

Comment: if you get complex values, you must have imaginary part ...

Comment: the complex values are only in "Answer" after the last line. until then isreal(Sb1)=1 and isreal(Sw1)=1.

Comment: can you give us a sample of the values ?

Comment: I think that I figure it out. "eigs" calculates the eigenvalues of the matrix, which includes SQRT in it... and I have negative values in Sb,Sw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that "eigs" calculates the eigenvalues of the matrix, which includes SQRT in it... and I have negative values in Sb,Sw